# Trying to make dictionary in JavaScript using array and objects

Tags: javascript, search

Today I was trying to make Trying to make dictionary in JavaScript using array and objects

I am trying to make search here using prompt

```html
<html>

<body style="font-size: 40px">
  <input type="text" id="myin">
  <button id="btn">Search</button>
  <div id="outputArea"></div>

  <script>
    var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");
    var output = "";
    var word = prompt("Enter something: ");

    var acronyms = [{
        acronym: "omg",
        meaning: "Oh MY God"
      },
      {
        acronym: "lol",
        meaning: "Laugh Out Loud"
      },
      {
        acronym: "lmao",
        meaning: "Laughing My Age Off"
      },
      {
        acronym: "wtf",
        meaning: "What This Function"
      }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < acronyms.length; i++) {
      if (acronyms[i].acronym === word) {
        word = acronyms[i].meaning;

        outputAreaRef.innerHTML = word;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when trying to use an input element with onclick button function rather than the prompt it does not work at all

here is the code with input and button

```html
<html>

<body style="font-size: 40px">
  <input type="text" id="myin">
  <button id="btn">Search</button>
  <div id="outputArea"></div>

  <script>
    var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");
    var output = "";
    var word = document.getElementById("myin");

    var acronyms = [{
        acronym: "omg",
        meaning: "Oh MY God"
      },
      {
        acronym: "lol",
        meaning: "Laugh Out Loud"
      },
      {
        acronym: "lmao",
        meaning: "Laughing My Age Off"
      },
      {
        acronym: "wtf",
        meaning: "What This Function"
      }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < acronyms.length; i++) {
      if (acronyms[i].acronym === word) {
        word = acronyms[i].meaning;

        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
          outputAreaRef.innerHTML = word;
        }
      }


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help where is the wrong

Sorry for my bad ENGLISH,

Comment: Seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes right away and the word will not be set yet. Hence nothing happens.
You have to move all the lookup logic (getting the current input and checking the dictionary) into the `onclick` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the input using `document.getElementById("myin").value`.Secondly create a `function` & attach it with the click handler of the button.

Inside this event handler get the value of the `input`,retrieving the value outside the click handler wont work.

```js
var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");
var output = "";


var acronyms = [{
    acronym: "omg",
    meaning: "Oh MY God"
  },
  {
    acronym: "lol",
    meaning: "Laugh Out Loud"
  },
  {
    acronym: "lmao",
    meaning: "Laughing My Age Off"
  },
  {
    acronym: "wtf",
    meaning: "What This Function"
  }
];

//Attach event listener to the button

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', searchWord)

function searchWord() {
  // need to get the value of the input
  var word = document.getElementById("myin").value;
  // if matches then show the value
  for (var i = 0; i < acronyms.length; i++) {
    // to lowerCase to make it case insensitive & trim to remove white space
    if (acronyms[i].acronym === word.toLowerCase().trim()) {
      outputAreaRef.innerHTML = acronyms[i].meaning;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myin">
<button id="btn">Search</button>
<div id="outputArea"></div>
```